# Transitive projects using in code [Updated: fixed]

Tags: gradle

I have 3 projects `app`, `lib1`, `lib2`. lib2 depends on lib1 next way:

lib2 build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':lib1')
}
```

app depends on lib1:

lib1 build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':lib2')
}
```

I want to use some lib1 classes directly in app. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: This should work like it is. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Casey yes, I already understood it, maybe somthing wrong with my ide

Comment: which IDE? do whatever the equivalent of refresh-dependencies is in your IDE.